# How do I add the results from a calculation to a new column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have this dataframe:

```
    Dt1     Dt2
0   8/21/19 8/31/19
1   8/21/19 8/31/19
2   8/21/19 8/31/19
3   8/30/19 8/31/19
```

Then I wrote this code:

```
for ind in df.index:
    date_str1 = df['Dt1'][ind]
    date_str2 = df['Dt2'][ind]
    date_object1 = datetime.strptime(date_str1, " %m/%d/%y")
    date_object2 = datetime.strptime(date_str2, " %m/%d/%y")
    d = date_object2-date_object1
    diff = d.days
    print(diff)
```

My results were:

```
10
10
10
1
```

This is what I expect of the results, and now what I want to do is for each row in the dataframe, I want to create a new column (date_diff) and add these results to each row so in the end I have something like this:

```
    Dt1     Dt2      Date_diff
0   8/21/19 8/31/19  10
1   8/21/19 8/31/19  10
2   8/21/19 8/31/19  10
3   8/30/19 8/31/19  1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
df['Dt1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dt1'])
df['Dt2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dt2'])

df['Date_diff'] = df['Dt2'].sub(df['Dt1']).dt.days
```

Answer (score 0):

Either create a column (with pure zeros, NaN or something else) and then write that in your loop at the end i.e `df.iloc[ind,"Date_Diff"]=diff` or have a list `Date_diff=[]` and then append in the end `Date_diff.append(diff)` - at last write that to your df `df["Date_diff"]=Date_diff`

Comment: Or do what Quang Hoang does